# Creating Inherited Response Objects

Tags: c#, asp.net, inheritance, response

I am writing some integration with a third-party eLearning platform that returns a variety of responses in different schemas depending on the function of my restful API call.  Since these responses come back in several different schemas, I'm trying to create a series of response object classes that inherit a base `Response` object class that would contain the common JSON sections (aka "data" and "message") and allow each individual response object to override or have additional members/classes based on the response being returned.

Here are a couple examples of how the schemas may differ.

Class Creation Return:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "row_index": 0,
      "success": true,
      "message": "string"
    }
  ]
}
```

User Creation Return:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "message": [
        {
          "id": "string",
          "message": "string"
        }
      ],
      "success": true,
      "user_id": 0
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see, the different responses have different schemas.  The Class Create only returns a `message` member within the data object, and the User Create has a separate `message` object altogether.

Since I can't have a class called `data` within each object because of ambiguity, I'm thinking I need to create a Base Response Object that contains the common members and allows me to override or add on the fly as necessary.

I've tried to create a Base Class:

```
public class BaseResponse
{
    public List<Data> data;
    public class Data
    {
        public bool success { set; get; }
    }
}
```

as well as an example derived class:

```
public class ClassroomResponse : BaseResponse
{
    public class Data
    {
        public int row_index { get; set; }            
        public string message { get; set; }   
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is only possible with functions and not classes as I'm trying to do above?  Is there a way to add additional members to the derived object's (`row_index` and `message` are not members of all responses, so I'd like to be able to grab those as needed)

Answer (score 2):

You could either create individual, distinct classes for each type, which might be the right option here depending on the other variants you haven't shown. Or you can use generics. There's a few ways you can do this, but here is one way you might do it.

A base class for the overall response:

```
public abstract class Response<TData>
{
    [JsonProperty("data")]
    public TData Data { get; set; }
}
```

A base class for the Data objects:

```
public abstract class BaseData<TMessage>
{
    [JsonProperty("success")]
    public bool Success { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("message")]
    public TMessage Message { get; set; }
}
```

The response type for class creation:

```
public class ClassData : BaseData<string>
{
    [JsonProperty("row_index")]
    public int RowIndex { get; set; }
}
```

The response types for user creation:

```
public class UserData : BaseData<UserMessage>
{
    [JsonProperty("user_id")]
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}

public class UserMessage
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("message")]
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

And finally the overall response types:

```
public class ClassResponse : Response<ClassData>
{ }

public class UserResponse : Response<UserData>
{ }
```

And now you can use the objects like you would normally:

```
var classData = new ClassResponse {Data = new ClassData {Message = ""}};
var classJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(classData);

var userData = new UserResponse {Data = new UserData {Message = new UserMessage {Message = ""}}};
var userJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userData);
```

Comment: My initial design had me using distinct classes for each response type (without using inheritance), but the problem there was that I could not have a class named "data" within all of those objects (which is a common member of all of the JSon responses).  It kept giving me a "Data is ambiguous" error because I had the "data" class defined in more of one of my response objects.

Comment: You don't need to call that class `Data` though, see my code above, you could call them `ClassData` and `UserData`, but the key point is the *name of the property* is `Data`.

Comment: Thank you! I decided to just create a separate response and use the JSonProperty to distinguish between different class names.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I will go by the generics route

Let's say that we have a response for **Class** creation as

```
public class ClassResponseObject {
    public int row_index { get; set; }
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; };
}
```

and for the **User** creation:

```
public class UserResponseObject {
    public int user_id { get; set; }
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public MessageResponseObject message { get; set; };
}
```

and for the **Message**

```
public class MessageResponseObject {
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; };
}
```

after seeing the above code we are able to find that we have success property common in both the responses, so lets create a base class with that property and inherit these classes with that.

```
public class BaseResponseObject {
    public bool success { get; set; }
}

public class ClassResponseObject : BaseResponseObject {
    public int row_index { get; set; }
    public string message { get; set; };
}

public class UserResponseObject : BaseResponseObject {
    public int user_id { get; set; }
    public MessageResponseObject message { get; set; };
}
```

at this point another common property we see is message, but both have different types. This can be solved with the use of generics. I am considering that there might be more types for the message property of the response, but it should work in either case.

for this let modify our **BaseResponseObject** and move the message property there

```
public class BaseResponseObject<TMessage> {
    public bool success { get; set; }
    public TMessage message { get; set; }
}
```

so our response objects will become something like this:

```
public class ClassResponseObject : BaseResponseObject<String> {
    public int row_index { get; set; }
}

public class UserResponseObject : BaseResponseObject<MessageResponseObject> {
    public int user_id { get; set; }
}
```

as the last step we need to define the final class for the actual response

```
public class APIResponse<TResponse> {
    public List<TResponse> data { get; set; }
}
```

now when you are capture the response for the **Class** creation you can simply capture it in

```
APIResponse<ClassResponseObject>
```

similarly for the **User** creation, capture it in

```
APIResponse<UserResponseObject>
```

I hope this helps.